# Jenkins nodejs script issue

Tags: node.js, jenkins, amazon-ec2, devops

have a script for Jenkins to run my Node.js application, and everything works fine. However, I have encountered a strange issue. In my last stage, which is the 'Logs' stage, if I remove this stage, my script runs successfully, shows a green tick, and a success message. But when I hit my server API, it's not working.

On the other hand, when I add the 'Logs' stage at the end and run it, it works fine, but the build keeps running (not completed). However, the server API functions correctly. I need to know how I can mark the build as successful even with the 'Logs' stage or what I should do to make it work without the 'Logs' stage.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    tools { nodejs "Node" }

    stages {
        stage('Clone Repository') {
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'master']],my_userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://mykeyhide@github.com/UmaiZ/node-devops-test']]])
            }
        }

        stage('Install Dependencies') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }

        stage('Stop Previous pm2 Process') {
            steps {
                sh 'pm2 kill -a'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Install pm2') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install pm2 -g'
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh 'pm2 start src/app.js --name my-app'
            }
        }
        stage('Log') {
            steps {
                sh 'pm2 logs my-app'
            }
        }

    }
}
```

I have search to find this issue but not able to resolved this.